# Context data lost in NextJS dev mode

Tags: next.js, react-context, next-link, nextui

In NextJS I’m using context, everything works fine but when I navigate with next/link then the context’s data is lost.

I have to fetch, set everything again. But when i create build and then check in production mode it works fine.

Why? How can i solve this? I really need this to work in dev mode too

I use JS not TS